# DNN (DotNetNuke) - Password reset stored in PasswordHistory table, not aspnet_Membership

Tags: passwords, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke, membership-provider, dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN site running DNN 7.04.00 (353).  I am not able to reset passwords on my site.  If I utilize the built-in password reset functionality I can receive the password reset email with a link.  I click the link, enter my email address and new password.  No matter what I do I keep getting an error that states, "Your new password was not accepted for security reasons. Please make sure to choose a password which does not match a previously used password and which is long and complex enough to meet the sites password complexity requirements."

Here's what's weird about it, I am entering a strong password that has never been used before.  When I do this, I can see the following things happen:

- Password reset link is sent with password token.  I can see this same token in the "Users" table.
- I follow the link. Attempt to reset the password using a valid and not previously used password.  No matter what, I receive the error above.
- The Users.PasswordResetToken column value is reset.  The Users.PasswordRestExpiration is set to null.  This tells me that I've used the token and it is no longer valid.
- Here's what's really strange... the aspnet_Membership.Password hash value is never changed... okay that makes since, I couldn't successfully change the password.  However, I now have a new entry in the PasswordHistory table.  The value here is hashed, however it looks like the reset password I entered was stored in the PasswordHistory table... the new password did not get stored in the aspnet_Membership table.

No matter what my password isn't accepted, however it's stored in the PasswordHistory table. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? A few notes that may help:

- Users register for accounts on my site via a custom registration module, not the default DNN registration module.
- In the DNN web.config I have the following settings

  - passwordStrengthRegularExpression is non-existent, I have removed this completely from web.config for troubleshooting.
  - enablePasswordReset is true
  - requireQuestionAndAnswer is true
  - passwordFormat is hashed

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the core code (UserController.ChangePasswordByToken()), it appears that the password history check happens before the password validation.  The history check also adds the attempted password to the history.  So it might be possible that if your password doesn't meet the validation rules, it would add it to history without changing it.

In Host > Host Settings > Advanced Settings > Membership Management, you can disable the history by unchecking "Enable password history".

But you need to focus on the password validation because that appears to be failing. It consists of three attributes of the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in your web.config:

- minRequiredPasswordLength
- minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters
- passwordStrengthRegularExpression

Like you mentioned, the passwordStrengthRegularExpression is empty or missing so that should not be of concern.  Make sure the password you are entering meets the minimum character length in minRequiredPasswordLength and contains the number of non-alphanumeric characters required by minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters.

Here is a snippet of code I'm using to register the new user:

```
newUser = new UserInfo();
newUser.PortalID = this.PortalId;
newUser.IsSuperUser = false;
newUser.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
newUser.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
newUser.DisplayName = txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text;
newUser.Email = txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim();
newUser.Username = txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim();
newUser.LastIPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
newUser.Profile.ProfileProperties["CompanyName"].PropertyValue = txtCompanyName.Text;
newUser.Profile.ProfileProperties["AddressLine1"].PropertyValue = txtAddressLine1.Text;
newUser.Profile.ProfileProperties["AddressLine2"].PropertyValue = txtAddressLine2.Text;
newUser.Profile.City = txtCity.Text;
newUser.Profile.ProfileProperties["State"].PropertyValue = ddlState.SelectedValue;
newUser.Profile.PostalCode = wmeZipCode.Text.Trim().TrimEnd('-');
newUser.Profile.Telephone = wmePhoneNumber.Text;
if (lblWmePhoneNumberExtension.Text.Trim().CompareTo(String.Empty) != 0) {      newUser.Profile.ProfileProperties["TelephoneExtension"].PropertyValue = wmePhoneNumberExtension.Text; }

var newMembership = new UserMembership(newUser);
newMembership.Approved = true;
newMembership.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
newMembership.IsOnLine = false;
newMembership.Password = txtPassword.Text;
newMembership.PasswordQuestion = ddlSecurityQuestion.SelectedValue;
newMembership.PasswordAnswer = txtSecurityQuestionAnswer.Text;
newUser.Membership = newMembership;

UserCreateStatus userStatus = membershipProvider.CreateUser(ref newUser);
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  Sadly, I still cannot get this to work.  I have those attributes with the following values: minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1".  I'm using a brand new password which I just made up, "ChickEnHea%d", and it still isn't working :(  

Do you have any other ideas?  The only thing that comes to mind is maybe my custom user registration module is not doing something it should in order for password resets to work.  I am using the UserMembership object to populate passwords on account creation.

Comment: You may have to provide a snip of your Login provider code.  Especially how the password is set.  Looking at a provider I built, I use the following lines to set the password on a UserInfo object:

/*Set Membership*/
UserMembership oNewMembership = new UserMembership(oUser) { Password = password };


/*Bind membership to user*/
oUser.Membership = oNewMembership;

Comment: I added my custom registration code to the original post.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I have narrowed down the error to this code in \admin\security\PasswordReset.ascx.cs

if (UserController.ChangePasswordByToken(PortalSettings.PortalId, username, txtPassword.Text, ResetToken) == false)
            {
                resetMessages.Visible = true;
                var failed = Localization.GetString("PasswordResetFailed", LocalResourceFile);
                LogFailure(failed);
                //lblHelp.Text = failed;
    lblHelp.Text = "here 4";
            }